# Throw error sólo imprime la primera línea

Tags: nodejs

Cuando lanzo un error en node.js yo espero que el error aparezca en la consola y aparte también espero que aparezca el número de línea donde ha ocurrido dicho error, así:

**Error:**

```
{ [Error: Unauthorized]
  message: 'Unauthorized',
  httpStatusCode: 401,
  status: 'UNAUTHORIZED',
  cause:
   { statusCode: 401,
     error: 'Unauthorized',
     message: '401 Unauthorized, Invalid OAuth Token' } }
```

**Código que lanza el error:**

```
throw err;
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
Unhandled rejection Error: { [Error: Unauthorized]
      message: 'Unauthorized',
      httpStatusCode: 401,
      status: 'UNAUTHORIZED',
      cause:
       { statusCode: 401,
         error: 'Unauthorized',
         message: '401 Unauthorized, Invalid OAuth Token' } } at ClientError (/some/path/Documents/my/project/node_modules/some-module/path/somefile.js:12:24)
```

Sin embargo, cuando el error consta de varias líneas como el que muestro anteriormente, sólo me muestra la primera línea en la consola, así:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unauthorized at ClientError (/some/path/Documents/my/project/node_modules/some-module/path/somefile.js:12:24)
```

¿Por qué sólo se muestra la palabra `Unauthorized` y no el mensaje completo?

Comment: ¿Estás dejando que node imprima la excepción por ti o estás utilizando alguna llamada como `console.log`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza estoy dejando que node imprima el error por mí.

Comment: Sería mejor que lo captures y utilices `console.log(error.stack)`

Comment: Imprime el mismo stack que puse arriba, incompleto a mi parecer.

Comment: Al parecer esa es la información que puede dar node. No puede brindarte la info que esperas a menos que hagas una manipulación extra de esa info.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tienes es un objeto `Error` con propiedades extra, posiblemente añadidas por el módulo que estés usando.  Node solamente imprime el stack trace del error y su primera línea es la propiedad `message` que es lo que estás observando.

Si quieres los detalles del objeto además del stack trace lo que puedes hacer es sobrecargar el comportamiento por defecto cuando existe una excepción no controlada.  Incluir esto a nivel de aplicación (no en el módulo, sino en la raíz):

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   console.log(error);
   console.log(error.stack);
   process.exit(1);
});
```

Ten mucho cuidado con esta función, aquí no debería haber nada más que llamadas a `console.log` (a menos que sepas que estás haciendo) y siempre debería acabar con `process.exit` ya que la aplicación se encuentra en un estado no recuperable. La documentación del evento: [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception).

Comment: Utiliza `console.error` en vez de `console.log` para imprimir errores.

Answer (score 0):

Después de  "`throw err`", usa `console.log(err)` para imprimirlo.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys, eso no funciona porque el throw detiene la aplicación, y poner el console.log antes es lo que estoy tratando de evitar.